# Can an Android application duplicate "Auto-rotate" functionality?

Tags: android

In other words, can an application sit in the background, read the g-sensor of the device, and accordingly set (or rotate) the view of the active Android application?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. You could use sensors to perhaps control *your* app, but you cannot impose your will upon other apps, any more than they can impose their will upon yours.